# How can I copy and parse the ip address from the command line?

Tags: cmd, gruntjs, ip

I'm using Grunt to run tasks, and running through the command, and I need my IP address for a script. I've found some solutions, but none that fit my need and I'm having trouble creating one because of my inexperience with Command Line.

One of the solutions is:

```
ipconfig | find "IPv4" | CLIP
```

But the result is:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xxx.xx
```

What I need is:

```
192.168.xxx.xx
```

Answer (score 1):

get the second token delimited by colon of the filtered line and set it to a variable. In a second step remove the space.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %i in ('ipconfig ^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%i
set ip=%ip: =%
echo ip=%ip%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to filter just lines you care about and awk to parse lines.

For instance lets assume you care about both ipv4 and ipv6 (enp5s0 is my interface):

```
$ ifconfig enp5s0 | grep 'inet' | awk '{ print $2 }' 
192.168.0.101
fe80::74c2:d0b8:5fa8:59fb
```

Or perhaps you care only about IPv4 - simple change in grep and you get just that:

```
$ ifconfig enp5s0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }'
192.168.0.10
```

Or only IPv6:

```
$ ifconfig enp5s0 | grep 'inet6' | awk '{ print $2 }'
fe80::74c2:d0b8:5fa8:59fb
```

Similarly you can change awk if you don't want to change lines you filter but want to change the parsing of a single line:

to get IPv4 mask:

```
$ ifconfig enp5s0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $4 }'
255.255.255.0
```

or both ip and mask:

```
$  ifconfig enp5s0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2; print $4 }'
192.168.0.101
255.255.255.0
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Simple command:
`ipconfig getifaddr en0`